# class extends inputAdapter in libGDX, but touch unrecognized

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm starting to play with libGDX, and developing a simple game with cubes and tiles.

My question is: after creating a generic class for screen management

```
   public abstract class BaseScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen {
       ...
   }
```

And the class where specific screen is implemented:

```
public class PlayingScreen extends BaseScreen {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.print("You touch on next position: (" + screenX + ", " + screenY + ")");
    }
}
```

When executing this easy example, nothing is logged in console... it worked previously when creating an specific class that extends InputAdapter and setting it as input processor:

```
public class UserInputManager extends InputAdapter {...}

public class MainGame implements ApplicationListener{
    ...
    public create(){
        UserInputManager uim = new UserInputManager();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(uim);
    }
    ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you implement any methods in the UserInputManager?

Comment: that was the previous version, where i implemented touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)  method (exactly the same as described)

Comment: Well since you're setting Gdx's input processor as the `UserInputManager` all events are going to go to that class. If you don't implement any methods they're not going to be received

Comment: But that was the old code. I just added that in order to show it was working before, but UserInputManager is no longer running in my code.. Maybe it was confusing, sorry for that :)

Comment: Are you setting the `BaseScreen` as your `InputProcessor`, using `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(basescreen)`?

Comment: No, the BaseScreen extends the inputAdapter, so i can implement directly touchDown method in its body (or any of its extended classes). BaseScreen just have the constructor.

Comment: @Springrbua !!! After reading once again your comment and understood it in a different way and... that was it! I forgot to add next line to my code: _Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);_ Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, so that you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to extend `InputAdapter`/implement `InputProcessor`, you also need to tell `LibGdx` which `InputProcessor` should now listen for input-events.
Therefor you need to call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this)` in your `BaseScreen`s `show` method.
If you have more than one `InputProcessor`, which should listen for input-events, you need to use an `InputMultiplexer` and call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer)`. Then you can add more `InputProcessor`s to this multiplexer.